# How to change the look of an inactive window in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend

When I change the style of my window to WindowStyle="None" and AllowsTransparency="True" I lose the inactive window visuals.  Is there a trigger I can use in the XAML style that can show a hidden mask or opacity changes in the main window when another window has focus? I'd like to be able to achieve this within the XAML and not programatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can change an opacity mask of window by changing `OpacityMask` property with trigger when  `Window.IsActive` is `true`. `OpacityMask` is a brush so you can provide anything you want, including gradient or something more complex. If I remember correctly framework will take only alpha channel from this brush.

Comment: I found IsActive right after posting. Here's what I added to the style for my custom title bar:

<Style.Triggers>
 <DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding Path=IsActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" >
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GlossGray}"/>
 </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>